# Do we need to force any questions tagging assembly to tag the architecture also?

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions

I saw a lot of questions, esp. from someone who had just learned assembly, asking about "assembly" with the tag [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) alone and no further mention of the architecture. Even though it was recommended in the tag info, people never bothered to read that

> Assembly language (asm) programming questions. BE SURE TO ALSO TAG with the processor and/or instruction set you're using, as well as the assembler. WARNING: For .NET assemblies, use the tag [.net-assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-assembly) instead. For Java ASM, use the tag [java-bytecode-asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-bytecode-asm) instead.

That makes answering the question sometimes not possible, and searching for the question more complex.

I suggest **requiring** the user to tag the architecture along with [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) instead of just a simple warning like above. In some cases that the question applies to any architectures, which is probably rare, it can be *confirmed explicitly* by the asker or we can *add a new tag* like [architecture-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/architecture-agnostic) for this.

Comment: or create a bunch of [assembly-arch] tags...

Comment: @Braiam that's not possible because there are so many architectures, many of which you may haven't heard of

Comment: The tag wiki already suggests tagging with an architecture and lists some.

Comment: @remyabel really? I've never asked one but I always see people asking with only assembly tag. In that case I think we should force them the tag like my idea

Answer (score 1):

Many questions are incorrectly tagged simply because the person asking doesn't know any better (either in the technology they're using or they don't fully understand how the site works). Some of those people will be first semester students at some random college/university and will be crapping themselves about the subject they've got themselves in to.

Sometimes you'll be able to take an educated guess as to the architecture based on any code they've included - in this case it's up to you or other community members to edit the post to add the correct tag(s).

If there's not enough information there to determine architecture then post a comment and ask - that's what the comments section is for.

This type of problem happens frequently elsewhere - for example someone will post a question about a ListBox and simply tag it with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and possibly [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) - not helpful at all. But that doesn't mean we need to build in extra tagging constraints - doing so won't end up educating many users anyway, they'll do the bare minimum necessary to get their question posted.

Comment: But in my experience this type of mistake is much more common. It's less likely that you'll encounter a question that lacks the language tag or tag for main problem. You can add an explanation to why they should tag the architecture when warning them